# cryptswap1 messages after reseizing root partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, cryptswap

I resized my windows and Ubuntu partitions yesterday to make my Ubuntu partition bigger and all went well, until i rebooted to Ubuntu.

I now receive a message upon boot saying: "Please enter passphrase for disk SanDisk_SD7UB3Q256G1001 (cryptswap1) on none!" After typing my password it continues te boot process and all seems fine, but I didn't had to do this before resizing the partition... I thought, ah well, it gives extra security so that is not a big deal...

But today I noticed the same messages appear when I reset my network-manager service giving me again this message:

fgod@fgod-ThinkPad-T440p:~$ sudo service network-manager restart
[sudo] password for fgod: 
Please enter passphrase for disk SanDisk_SD7UB3Q256G1001 (cryptswap1) on none!

So I guess there is something else going on...

I opened Gparted but the swap partition is still on swapon. I checked the /etc/crypttab, but the UUID is set to the right swap partition. The following is in my crypttab file:

```
cryptswap1 UUID=319bec78-95b7-4cd2-ae18-0bc6c0eac052 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

After that i checked fstab, but there too the UUID was set to the right partition. This is what is inside my fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name 
devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=59856087-9219-4b06-9172-f29884cceda2 /               ext4    
errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
#UUID=ECA5-87F9  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda8 during installation
#UUID=319bec78-95b7-4cd2-ae18-0bc6c0eac052 none            swap    sw              
0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
UUID=ECA5-87F9  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
```

As this is my laptop from work I am afraid to mess it up as reinstalling would mean a lot of hassle to set everything back up.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: swap is the only thing you encrypted ???

Comment: I don't know anymore as I did the install 1,5 year ago... But i have never had to put in my password for this before

Comment: Hard to give advice if you do not know your partition / encryption scheme. If all you have is an encrypted swap I would delete it and use a regular, encrypted swap partition.

Comment: wouldn't it delete any important stuff if I delete the partition and make a new one?

Comment: No swap is temp space.

Comment: What is the safest way to delete and remake the swap and make sure everything is setup correctly?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_do_I_add_or_modify_a_swap_partition.3F . Just unmount the current swap partition first, delete it, make a new one, edit /etc/crypttab and /etc/fstab

Comment: hey I'm having the same issue do you have a fix for this?

Comment: the fix for me was to delete the swap and remake it like Panther said (sorry about not telling, forgot to answer this) but you could also try the solution HyperActive gave me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and found that reinstalling ecryptfs-utils and updating grub worked for me:

```
$ sudo apt install ecryptfs-utils --reinstall
$ sudo update-grub
```